How should I separate UseCases based on the requirements?
So I'm trying to understand clean architecture principles.
One of the most confusing for me is the UseCase layer. I have read a lot of explanation about what is that, but I still can not decide how many use cases should I create from 1 requirement...
My current problem is, I have a Firestore and Room database. I store the last update date in Firestore as well as in Room.
In MainActivityViewModel I want to compare the local and remote update dates, and if it is required, I want to update the local tables.
Currently I have two use cases, but I could be 3 or 1, based on how I should separate them.
The first useCase  gets the remote and local dates, and it creates a list of table names which needed to be updated.
The second UseCase basically grabs the result from the first one, updates the tables and the dates in local database.
My opinion is I need only 1 useCase which updates the tables if needed based on the local and remote dates.
Am I right? Or what is the "rule" regarding to useCases?

When defining use cases, I find it helpful to consider the following criteria:

Goal: The user (actor) should be able to execute a single use case and receive a desired behavior or response.
Precondition and Postcondition: The system status before and after the use case should be clearly recognizable (e.g. postcondition in your case: data has been updated).

For the process you are describing, I would wonder if internal operations or even the fact that two databases exist are relevant the user (actor). So from the user's perspective, I would go for one use case. Probably, neither the first part of the process of creating table entries nor the second part of performing the database updates are sufficient to reach a reasonable goal and postcondition.
